# How can I fill order from my contract by using V4 API and contract?

Tags: 0x

I'm trying to fill order from my contract by using 0x V4 API and contract on Mainnet.

So far I'm guessing that I should call batchFill function in this contract.

https://etherscan.io/address//0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff#writeProxyContract

But I have no idea what data I need to pass to "fillData (tuple)". Could anyone help me?
Also, I found that "exchangeProxy" contract is deployed to Polygon network but it seems that the interface is different. How can I fill order on the Polygon network?

https://polygonscan.com/address/0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff#writeProxyContract

I'm using API call like this to get orderbooks information.

https://api.0x.org/sra/v4/orderbook?baseToken=0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2&quoteToken=0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48&perPage=1000

I found v4 contract address here

https://protocol.0x.org/en/latest/basics/addresses.html#exchange-v4
https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/packages/contract-addresses/addresses.json

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things.

1. Etherscan has the wrong ABI for the Exchange Proxy so don't use that as a reference. The actual interfaces for the features you're interested in can be found [here](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/contracts/zero-ex/contracts/src/features/interfaces/INativeOrdersFeature.sol) and [here](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/contracts/zero-ex/contracts/src/features/interfaces/IBatchFillNativeOrdersFeature.sol) (they both exist on the same `0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff` address).
2. `batchFillLimitOrders()` is used to fill *multiple* orders. If you're just trying to fill a single order, you can just call `fillLimitOrder()`.
3. Otherwise, the process is fairly typical: Set an allowance on the Exchange Proxy `0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff` for the token you're selling (taker token) then call `fillLimitOrder()` on that order.

More info can be found here https://protocol.0x.org/en/latest/basics/functions.html

Comment: Thanks I managed to make it work